# BottomNavigationBar // Controlling Height with SizedBox leads to overflow

Tags: flutter, responsiveness, flutter-bottomnavigation

**The goal**:
Instead of using the hard coded height for the BottomNavigationBar, I want to size it as a fraction of the screen height.

**My approach so far**: I figured out that I can wrap the BottomNavigationBar in a SizedBox and control the height that way. Code at the botom.

**The problem**: I get overflows with the BottomNavigationBarItems on various devices.

[image]

I tried scaling the icons using the height of the SizedBox, but I need to make the items pretty small to avoid the overflow so that is not an option.

**The code**:

```
final bottomNavHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.heigth * 0.085;


bottomNavigationBar: SizedBox(
      height: bottomNavHeight,
      child: BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: _selectPage,
        iconSize: bottomNavHeight * 0.45,
        showSelectedLabels: false,
        showUnselectedLabels: false,
        currentIndex: _selectedPageIndex,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        items: [
          //home
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home, color: _customColorScheme['Icon 1']),
            activeIcon:
                Icon(Icons.home, color: _customColorScheme['Icon 2']),
            label: '',
          ),
          //favorite
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon:
                Icon(Icons.favorite, color: _customColorScheme['Icon 1']),
            activeIcon:
                Icon(Icons.favorite, color: _customColorScheme['Icon 2']),
            label: '',
          ),
          //loockback
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.bar_chart,
                color: _customColorScheme['Icon 1']),
            activeIcon: Icon(Icons.bar_chart,
                color: _customColorScheme['Icon 2']),
            label: '',
          ),
          //info & support
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.info, color: _customColorScheme['Icon 1']),
            activeIcon:
                Icon(Icons.info, color: _customColorScheme['Icon 2']),
            label: '',
          ),
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]
you can use like this like css break

```
  final bottomNavHeight = getMyheight(context);

 getMyheight(BuildContext context) {
    var mheight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    if (mheight < 300)
      return mheight * 0.80;
    else if (mheight < 400)
      return mheight * 0.2;
    else if (mheight < 500)
      return mheight * 0.2;
    else if (mheight < 600)
      return mheight * 0.2;
    else if (mheight < 800)
      return mheight * 0.3;
    else
      return mheight * 0.085;
  }
```

**TIP**

For Discrete jump i used windows run
NB: some packages dependent on platform so may exception so for ui testing it best discrete screen.

> On Windows, desktop support is enabled on Flutter 2.10 or higher. On
> macOS and Linux, desktop support is disabled by default in the stable
> channel. You can manually enable it with one of these commands,
> depending on which platform you are running:

```
flutter config --enable-macos-desktop
flutter config --enable-linux-desktop
flutter config --enable-windows-desktop
```

[image]

This package use to test different screen size[devicepreview](https://pub.dev/packages/device_preview)

```
device_preview: ^1.0.0
```

Comment: If I understand it correctly, this gives me discrete jumps in value that will work well? Also, what do you use, so yu can test different sizes by dragging the size? Looks usper useful.

Answer (score 0):

The bottom-overflow starts around <704. `BottomNavigationBarItem`'s is not getting enough space.

You can  remove `SizedBox` and just start with `BottomNavigationBar`, it will solve the issue.

```dart
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(....)
```

Comment: But then I‘m not controlling the size of the navigation bar anymore but use the hard coded value.

Comment: `BottomNavigationBar` wrapped with  `SizedBox` and providing `.heigth * 0.085` is controlling the size of `BottomNavigationBar`. If you increase to `.heigth * 0.09` overflow will solve but may cause again on different level calculation.